# Updating state of array2 after a drag and drop, updates array1 which is the source of the drag and drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

Both states are updating.

I have 2 arrays in state, array1 and array2, both are mapped on 2 different tables, if I drag over to the 2nd table, I filter [...array1] using the e.dataTransfer.getData('id') that I set to get the item, then setState on array2 that adds the filtered item.

I tried using the spread operator to prevent mutating the state, but still keeps on editing.

item is an object.

drop handler:

```
handleDrop = (e) => {
    const { array1, array2 } = this.state
    const id = e.dataTransfer.getData('id')
    const item = [...array1].filter(item => item.id === id)[0]
    const newArray2 = [ ...array2, item ]
    this.setState({ array2 : newArray2 })
}
```

edit's title of item:

```
editItemTitle = (id, title) => {
    const { array2 } = this.state
    const index = [...array2].findIndex(item => item.id === id)
    let newArray2 = [...array2]
    newArray2[index].values.title = title
    this.setState({array2: newArray2})
  }
```

I expected array1 to stay the same, but it also gets updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, `item` is hopefully an object/array and in `handleDrop` function, we are setting `item` as the last element of `newArray2`. This copies the reference rather than copying `item`.

To avoid this, try to copy(shallow/deep, depending on the need), as show below(shallow copy, assuming `item` is an `object`)

```
 const newItem = { ...item };
 newItem.value = { ...item.value };
 const newArray2 = [ ...array2, newItem ];
```

Comment: You need to copy the `values` object too which is being copied, which usually requires `deep` copy of `item`. The above example only shows an example of shallow copy.